# Difficulty checking out svn project with alternate username

Tags: svn, ssh, svn-checkout

I'm trying to check out a project from a school server, but it attempts to use my computer login name instead of my server login name, so it fails.

my commands:

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://[server name and stuff]/[school login name]
```

and it says:

```
[computer login]@[server name]'s password:
```

which doesn't exist.

I attempted to use the `--username` parameter:

```
svn checkout --username [school login] svn+ssh://[server name and stuff]/[school login name]
```

but it requests the same password for the same nonexistent user.  What am I doing wrong with my checkout command?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://[school login name]@[server name]/[svn path]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply!  I get "svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly" :(

Comment: can you try a normal ssh connect? (`ssh [user]@[server]`)

Comment: huh, I just tried it and it didn't go through.  I can ssh into a different school server, and svn checkout onto that account, but I guess I can't from my home computer?

Comment: can you try with `ssh -vvv user]@[server]` ? the `-vvv` switch make the command more verbose. Update your question with the command output, which should help identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

(1) clear out all client credentials cache
http://chestofbooks.com/computers/revision-control/subversion-svn/Client-Credentials-Caching-Serverconfig-Netmodel-Credcache.html

(2) Is the school's server misconfigured (or intentionally configured that way)? For example, it may be hardwired to require you to connect from a school computer.